# python C api: how to use the "list(…)" operator

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have defined a python-type using `PyTypeObject` etc… and I have defined a `.tp_str` to support the `str(myObj)` feature… because my type has also a **[list]** like behavior… I would like to support the `list(myObj)` feature too. my problem is that I miss a `.tp_list` entry to support this.

my question… how can I do this?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

There's no `__list__` hook at Python level either. Like implementing the same behavior at Python level, you have to make instances of your class iterable. `list(yourobj)` will then iterate over your object to gather elements into a list.

The C-level slots corresponding to `__iter__` and `__next__` are [`tp_iter`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/typeobj.html#c.PyTypeObject.tp_iter) and [`tp_iternext`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/typeobj.html#c.PyTypeObject.tp_iternext), and they work pretty much like `__iter__` and `__next__` do. If you haven't written an iterator class manually before, I suggest doing it in Python for practice before doing it in C (and remember that the iterator should be a different object from your list-like object).

Aside from iteration, you should also implement the [sequence protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/typeobj.html#c.tp_as_sequence) if your object really is supposed to be list-like.